# Millions of polygon data in map for iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I want to know which polygons intersect (contains, contained or overlapped) with current MKMapView screen from millions of polygon data in a geojson file. It can be handled by using QuadTree when I worked for millions of points data. But it seems this doesn't work for Polygons.

I'm wondering what the best strategy is? What is the suitable algorithm and data struct I can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531425/find-rectangle-contains-point-from-array-of-rectangles

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya This is still about searching a point.

Comment: I found GKRtree should be for this purpose. But I could not find any tutorial for this. The Apple document doesn't explain the principle behind this data structure and algorithm.